# Update from Kubuntu 16.04 to Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, kubuntu

I want to update from Kubuntu 16.04 to Kubuntu 18.04. I googled a bit and found the command `kdesudo "do-release-upgrade -m desktop -f DistUpgradeViewKDE"`. But after I typed this into the konsole, I got the message `No new release found.`

So how could I upgrade? :) Thank you!

Comment: I would swear this has been asked multiple times in the last couple of days.

Comment: Yes but not with my problem, I didn't find such a problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try clearing out the `~/.cache/update-manager-core/` directory and re-trying your steps.

If that doesn't work try

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

`-c` checks what version is available.  Replace it with `-d` if it's the version you want.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if that applies to KUbuntu - for Ubuntu, the 18.04 LTS release is still missing on this [list](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts) as of today (10 Aug. 2018).

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/bionic/release/ shows it's been out since 7/25 : `kubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso 2018-07-25 03:29 1.8G`